# I am trying to identify a hot pepper plant in my garden

Tags: identification, peppers

I got a bag with a variety of hot pepper seeds. I cannot identify this one type that is growing in my garden. The peppers are growing upwards and are a bulbous green right now. I need to know what type so I know when to harvest etc.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: Where did you get the bag of seeds from?

Comment: Once the plant has some small, green peppers on it, it will be relatively easy to tell what kind they're going to be. As they grow, they will develop into miniature versions of the mature pepper. At that point you should be able to tell what kind they will be, and therefore how big they will get and what color they will be when ripe.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it looks more like a sweet or bell pepper due to size of the leaves and the nature of the stalk, but time will tell you what it is and when to harvest, most peppers when truly ripe will change colors to a degree

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of peppers, but fortunately, I can tell it's Capsicum annuum, and we know the fruit shape, at the very least. The only hot variety I know with that shape is [Satan's Kiss](https://www.timeless-tomatoes.com/satans-kiss.html) (I grew that one last year, and all of the fruits were round like in your linked picture), but I imagine there are other matches.